# Error Control Operator passed by reference

Tags: php

Looking into some legacy PHP code I have found following passage:

`$template=$this->replace('<!--placeholder-->', @$template);`

calling the function:

```
function replace($placeholder, &$template)
    {
        $target = preg_quote($placeholder, "/");
        return preg_replace( /* ...regex&target... */, /* ...replacement... */, $template);
    }
```

On execution it logs the following:

> PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference in

So I read about the Error Control Operator, but I do not get why it is used on the parameter there. And was not able to find any example that uses it this way. When removing it, it did not change the behavior of the software.

Why does the error occur? It was working already before removing and states that it suppresses errors.

Comment: If the code you posted is the entire code of method `replace()` then there is no need to pass the second argument by reference. The method does not modify it. Remove `&` from the function signature and remove `@` from the function call. Most probably the author of the code added it in an attempt to suppress the notice. I think it should be put in front of `$this->replace()` to work. Anyway, do not use the error suppression operator. It does not solve any problem, it only hides it. Code that works with error suppressed on the current version of PHP could not work any more on the next version.

Comment: Passing arguments by reference is another code smell. Avoid it. Let the function return a new value (it could be one of its arguments) and assign it to the variable that needs to be modified (how this code already does).

Comment: The `@` operator is a crutch. Stop using it and fix the errors instead.

Comment: thank you two for your input. trying to understand why was my goal, and at least to know that you see it similar to me helps a lot. i'm going to refactor it like you suggested it